# Encoding problem with php short of retyping evertin by hand how can I fix it

Tags: php, encoding

I have tried to fix this myself and I just keep on making it worse. It was stupid but I played a little with the encoding and now I am getting

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING 
on line 1

First It double spaced everything which was annoying But I could live with it. Now if I copy the text into microsoft notepad I loose all cariage returns.

I take it in the end I want to be in utf-8. Is there way to do this without retyping.

I am using windows and a shared host. As a side note I have generated several thousand lines of code.

I should mention i have been using netbeans.

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: code sample please

Comment: What format is it in now? Where are you copying it from? What editor are you using? What did you do to begin with?

Comment: I am using shared hosting at hostmonster.com

Comment: How can I send a code sample I can't see the problem.

Comment: What format is it in now various. I copied it out of netbeans.

Comment: I have no Idea what I did to begin with.

Comment: I am sorry I am not being very helpful. Thanks and will try to respond as best I can

Comment: I do remember how this started I was using to net beans at home and at work and thats when the double space started showing up.

Comment: Should be no problem to roll back to a previous, clean revision before you started playing around with encodings, right? I mean, you ***are*** using a version control system, right, ***right***? If not, let this be a lesson. ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Hm. you said that you've played with encoding? Well, this is my blind guess...

So, you've got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_STRING on line 1

Do you have something like this (line 1) ???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

if you have, be sure that encoding value is lowercase like `utf-8` not `UTF-8`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

or try removing this line.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> I do have this though

Comment: @George, What's your first line?

Comment: <?php

class FormDirectorAbstract_AwardNominationFormCgi extends FormDirectorAbstract {

Comment: only <?php on hte first line class is on the second line

Comment: @George, then I really don't see a problem on line 1!